# calculating the sum of digits in a list in python

Tags: python

I am new to math problems in python but basically i have the following code:

```
a = list(range(1,10000))
str(a)

sum_of_digits = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(a[9998]))
print(sum_of_digits)
```

this allows me to calculate the sum of the digits of a given number in the list a. but instead of feeding numbers into this one by one, i want an efficient way to calculate the sum of the digits of all the numbers in a and print them all out at once. I can't seem to figure out a solution but i know the answer is probably simple. any help is appreciated!

edit: i didnt know this post would get this much attention, for those wanting more clarification i basically want to know which digits in the list of range 1,9999 has a sum of 34 or more. i think everyone thought i simply wanted to take the sum of digits of each list element and then compile a total sum. in any case, that method helped me solve the actual problem

Comment: Do you want the sum of digits of the numbers in a list, or for all the numbers up to a certain limit, which might be much larger than what can be stored in a list or computed in a loop, i.e. up to billions or trillions?

Comment: the sum of digits of individual numbers in a list

Answer (score 1):

A good, straightforward way to do this is to use the modulo `%` operator, along with floor division `\\`:

```
total_sum = 0
for num in a:
    sum_of_digits = 0
    while (num != 0):  
        sum_of_digits = sum_of_digits + (num % 10) 
        num = num//10
    total_sum = total_sum + sum_of_digits
print total_sum
```

Here, the expression `n % 10` returns the remainder of dividing `n` by 10, or in other words, it returns the digit in the units place of that number. What the while loop is doing is repeatedly dividing the number by 10, then adding the number in the units place to the total.

Note that the `\\` (floor division) is important here, as it gets rid of any decimal value in the number, which is needed for modulo `%` to work properly.

**Note**: This solution is *massively* more efficient than any algorithm which relies on `str()`.

Comment: The algorithm should work, but both of your notes are (at least partially) wrong. 1) You are right, this should be faster than conversion to `str`, but the complexity is the same. For a number of k digits, you would also have to do `%10` and `//10` k times. 2) The numbers in the list will _not_ be modified, since you only reassign to `num`, not to `a[i]`.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k for spot checking me =)

Comment: Also, it is faster, but not _massively_. It is about 40% faster then a list comprehension converting to `str` and back to `int`, and just about 10% faster than `sum(map(int, str(n)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum(int(i) for j in range(1,10000) for i in str(j))
```

It is the same, but works slowly:

```
lst = []
for j in range(10000):
    for i in str(j):
        lst.append(int(i))
print(sum(lst))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27626978)

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara: Why do you say this doesn't provide an answer? I'd prefer to see more explanation of the approach to help new developers understand the logic, and I can't attest to whether or not this is the most efficient—or even correct—approach. But that's what the voting mechanism is for.

Comment: this gives me with the number 18000 when i print it. this is the correct answer according to the blurry explanation that I gave but what i was actually looking for is updated in the post. thanks anyways!

Comment: this is a really interesting answer, would you care to explain how the code works? it calculates the sum of all digits in one line. I was wondering if I could alter it to do this for individual elements in a list and see which sum is greater than 34

Answer (score 0):

> i want an efficient way to calculate the sum of the digits of all the numbers in a

If you truly want an efficient way, do not calculate the sum of the digit sum of all the individual numbers. Instead, calculate the total digit sum  of the entire range<sup>1</sup> at once.

For example, in the range up to and including `123`, we do not have to write out all the individual numbers to see that the last digit will cycle through the numbers 1-9 a total of 12 times, plus the numbers 1-3 once. The middle digit cycles through 1-9 once, showing each 10 times, and then another 10 times 1 and 4 times 2. And for the first digit, only the 1 appears 24 times. Thus, the total is `45*12 + 1+2+3 + 45*10 + 10 + 8 + 24 = 1038`.

You can put this into a recursive formula using "a bit" of modulo magic.

```
def dsum(n, f=1, p=1):
    if n:
        d, r = divmod(n, 10)
        k = (45*d + sum(range(r)))*f + r*p
        return dsum(d, f*10, p + f*r) + k
    return 0
```

This yields the same results as the "naive" approach, but with a running time of O(log n) instead of O(n) it can be used to calculate the digit sum of ridiculously large ranges of numbers.

```
>>> n = 1234567
>>> sum(int(c) for i in range(1, n+1) for c in str(i))
32556016
>>> dsum(n)
32556016
>>> dsum(12345678901234567890)
1047782339654778234045
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is assuming your list is always a range of numbers starting at 1 up to some upper bound, although this would also work for a range not starting at 1 by calculating the digit sum for the upper bound and then subtracting the digit sum for the lower bound. If the list is *not* a range, then there's no way around calculating the digit sum for all the individual numbers, though.